# Inserting a new attribute in object in Python

Tags: python, list

Hello I'm new to Python and working on a small project. I'm trying to put a new attribute into an object,but somehow whatever I'm trying the attribute is not reaching in the response.

Here's the part of my code:

```
@app.get("/news-article/")
async def create_news_article(url: str):
  from newsplease import NewsPlease

  headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  }

  result = requests.get(url, headers)

  status = "SUCCESS" if result.status_code == 200 else "FAILED"

  data = {
    "status": status,
    "newsArticle": NewsPlease.from_html(result.content.decode(), url=url)
  }

  return data

async def insert_image(news):
   for feed, entries in news.items():
      for index, item in enumerate(entries):
        try:
          link = item.link

          article = create_news_article(link).json()

          article_image_url = json.dumps(article['newsArticle']['image_url'])

          # setattr(news["entries"][index], 'image', article_image_url)
          # news.entries[index].insert(index, {'image': article_image_url})
          # item.image = article_image_url
          news.entries[index]['image'] = article_image_url
        except AttributeError:
          print(f"Error extracting information from item: {item}\n")

@app.get("/latest")
async def create_news_latest():
    news = google_news.top_news()

    await insert_image(news)

    data = {
      "news": news,
    }

    return data
```

So basically what I try is to put a new attribute "image" (which is not yet existing) to my "news" object, but the response still stays like that:

```
{
  "news": {
    "entries": [
      {
        "title": "Trump fails to secure bond for $454 mln judgment in civil fraud case as asset seizures loom - Reuters",
        "title_detail": {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "language": null,
          "base": "",
          "value": "Trump fails to secure bond for $454 mln judgment in civil fraud case as asset seizures loom - Reuters"
        },
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "alternate",
            "type": "text/html",
            "href": "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMic2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnJldXRlcnMuY29tL2xlZ2FsL3RydW1wLWhhcy1mYWlsZWQtZ2V0LWFwcGVhbC1ib25kLTQ1NC1tbG4tY2l2aWwtZnJhdWQtanVkZ21lbnQtbGF3eWVycy1zYXktMjAyNC0wMy0xOC_SAQA?oc=5"
          }
        ],
        "link": "https://news.google.com/rss/articles/CBMic2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnJldXRlcnMuY29tL2xlZ2FsL3RydW1wLWhhcy1mYWlsZWQtZ2V0LWFwcGVhbC1ib25kLTQ1NC1tbG4tY2l2aWwtZnJhdWQtanVkZ21lbnQtbGF3eWVycy1zYXktMjAyNC0wMy0xOC_SAQA?oc=5",
        "id": "CBMic2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnJldXRlcnMuY29tL2xlZ2FsL3RydW1wLWhhcy1mYWlsZWQtZ2V0LWFwcGVhbC1ib25kLTQ1NC1tbG4tY2l2aWwtZnJhdWQtanVkZ21lbnQtbGF3eWVycy1zYXktMjAyNC0wMy0xOC_SAQA",
        "guidislink": false,
        "published": "Mon, 18 Mar 2024 18:40:00 GMT",
        "published_parsed": [2024, 3, 18, 18, 40, 0, 0, 78, 0],
        "summary": "",
        "summary_detail": {
          "type": "text/html",
          "language": null,
          "base": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        "source": {
          "href": "https://www.reuters.com",
          "title": "Reuters"
        },
        "sub_articles": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Can some Python expert maybe help me out here? :)

I tried to put it in the object in this ways:

```
          # Option 1. setattr(news["entries"][index], 'image', article_image_url)
          # Option 2. news.entries[index].insert(index, {'image': article_image_url})
          # Option 3. item.image = article_image_url
          # Option 4. news.entries[index]['image'] = article_image_url
```

Unfortunately none of the worked...

Comment: `create_news_article()` is async, so you need `article = (await create_news_article(link)).json()`.

Comment: `news.entries[index]['image']` should just be `item['image']`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention, I tried `item['image]` as well, but this also didn't work. :(
But I will try, if changing it to `article = (await create_news_article(link)).json()` will fix it today, when I reach in home.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, I changed it as you said, but the response is unfortunately still the same. The only thing what changed is, that with the await the fetch call takes now like 30 to 40 seconds to finish instead of like 2 or 3 seconds without the await.